# How to match in bash specific hash in source file and replace by it match in target file?

Tags: html, bash, file, sed

I would like to copy md5 hash from `source.html` to my another static file in another docker image to enable browser caching, specifically how can I replace `/app.css` by `/app-67131f3c5c4e7877d424.css` and `/app.js` by `/app-67131f3c5c4e7877d424.js` in bash script in neat and tidy way?

source.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="app-67131f3c5c4e7877d424.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app-67131f3c5c4e7877d424.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

existing_file_as_target.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that this is simplified version and I have a lot of script tags etc.

For now I just copy `app-67131f3c5c4e7877d424.css` to `app.css` but this approach disables browser cache.

Comment: What have you tried for this task?

Comment: I just copy file with digest to without it because with sed I don't know how to redirect dynamic match to target file in proper place

Comment: you have to use html,xml parser for this job, maybe xmlstartlet as you tagged bash, sed or other text manipulation tools could fail for special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with Perl, not with `sed`:

```sh
   $ digest=`perl -ne 's{src="app-([0-9a-f]{20}\.js")}{print $1}e' source.html`
   $ perl -npe "s{src=\"/app\.js\"}{src=\"/app-$digest.js\"}" existing_file_as_target.html >new.html
```

The file `new.html` contains what you need.

Note: In your `source.html` the URL was `app-DIGEST.js` *without* a leading slash. In `existing_file_as_target.html` you had `/app.js` *with* a leading slash. My solution takes that into account. If this assumption is wrong, insert or delete the slash as needed.

The solution also assumes that the digest is always exactly 20 lowercase hex characters.